# ExpressJS Middleware Setup

Tags: model-view-controller, node.js, express

I have a notifications system for my website (set up in Node.js) and I'm using an MVC pattern. In my controllers, I do a check if there's a `flash` message:

```
  if flashMessages = req.flash()
    if flashMessages.gritterMsgs
      for flashMessage in flashMessages.gritterMsgs
```

The only issue is I have to do this for **every** controller and every function **within** that controller. Is there someway to include this once (perhaps as middleware)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Express](http://expressjs.com/guide.html) already has view helpers, you can setup the session and flash objects for views like so:

```
app.dynamicHelpers({
  session: function(req, res){
    return req.session;
  },
  flash: function(req, res){
    return req.flash();
  }
});
```

Then in your views you can directly use the `flash` object (which is set in the controller like so: `req.flash = "my flash stuff"`.

Here's an example: https://github.com/alessioalex/Nodetuts/blob/master/express_samples/app.js